# What is the approximate accuracy of ASDE-X?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airport, radar

Can anyone suggest some ballpark figures for estimating the tracking accuracy of [ASDE-X systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASDE-X) at airports? Specifically, I'm trying to get a sense of the error (± x meters) that can be expected from ASDE-X when fixing the position of an aircraft.

Comment: Are you asking how accurately ASDE-X can fix the position of a single aircraft? And what's the relevance of PDARS (it's a data analysis system)?

Comment: @Pondlife.  Sorry I should have been clearer.  The way you phrased it is correct.  Specifically, I'm trying to get a sense of the error (± x meters) that can be expected from ASDE-X when fixing the position of an aircraft.  PDARS is not relevant, I just usually have found the two referenced together which is why I did so.  I hope that helps.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I edited your question with some information from your comment; you can edit it again yourself if my changes aren't useful, of course.

Comment: @Pondlife Thanks, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FAA has [a bunch of information](https://www.faa.gov/search/?omni=MainSearch&q=asde-x) on ASDE-X, most of which I personally have no idea how to interpret correctly. The [ASDE-X procurement specification](https://faaco.faa.gov/attachments/153CAB60-EF5B-74EF-207588DC9BA9FA65.doc) in particular has a lot of technical details on radar performance and although I didn't understand much of it I did notice this requirement:

> **3.6.3   Map Registration**
>
> The display of target data shall [R306] be registered to the display map with an accuracy of at least 20 feet.

So whatever the *technical* capabilities of the system are, *operationally* it seems that you can assume it's accurate to within 20ft, which seems to be reasonable in the context of large aircraft. You may be able to get more out of the documentation than I could, of course.