# Do airports use buried cables to detect planes or vehicles moving?

Tags: safety, air-traffic-control

I've been [thinking](http://www.yankee-dreamer.com/airportsensorsystem.htm) about the possibility of using a buried cable to detect aircraft or other vehicles moving on the ground at an airport. The military already uses this technology for other purposes and it would avoid some issues with radio- or radar-based solutions, like ground clutter.

Are buried-cable systems already in use for tracking surface movements at airports?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to detect, hence difficult to answer. Movements and intrusion can be detected by so many ways, depending on the purpose. What is not already detected or not well enough?... Could you clarify your question by editing your post? Thanks.

Comment: See Also: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19087/is-there-any-system-to-warn-of-runway-incusion & http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9960/what-is-the-approximate-accuracy-of-asde-x

Answer (score 3):

Airport ground support vehicles, like the aircraft they support, are outfitted with transmitters that broadcast thier GPS position to ATC ground controllers (ADS-B). That infrastructure is already in place and implementation is ramping up rapidly.

I think that may solve the problem you are addressing unless you are thinking of a security issue.

Comment: Not to mention ground radar and a number of other systems.